# Swift punctuation

Tags: swift

```
let observation = request.progress.observe(\Progress.fractionCompleted, options: [.initial, .new]) { (progress, change) in }
```

What does "\" mean before **Progress** word?

Comment: See [Key-Path Expression](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Expressions.html#//appleref/swift/grammar/wildcard-expression) in the Swift book

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a keyPath t0 a property in the progress

```
\Progress.fractionCompleted
```

that the observer will be triggered when it's changed , as an example suppose you want to do some action when a textfield is hidden , you write observer like this

```
let ob = myTexF.observe(\UITextField.isHidden) { (textF,ob) in

    /// do action 
}
```

//

In your code you can also replace

```
\Progress.fractionCompleted
```

with

```
\.fractionCompleted
```

as the property will be mapped to the element directly before `.observe`